# list definitions not showing in site definition sub site

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am facing some issue i beleive you could help me.

The Scenario is basically: the solution has a site collection on root web and some sub sites under 
this site collection both site collection and sub sites should be create based on site definition solution

I have created site definition solution which includes some custom content types and lists.

This solution also should create some other sub sites under the root site (site collection) based on my site definition template.

the problem is, the list is not showing in sub sites but the lis showing in root site(site collection)

this is the problem.

Comment: Add the feature XML (note: not the schema.xml) of your list definition to your question. What is the scope of the feature: Web or Site?

Comment: the scope of the feature is: web

Comment: looks like your custom feature is not activated on the web's. Get the ID of the web level custom feature and activate it using Powershell to validate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your Content Types and List Definitions to be available in all sites in the Site Collection, define your Feature to be Site scoped.